# datatables fixed column on display laoding processing

Tags: ajax, datatables

I'm using FixedColumns plugins for my DataTables components. And also i'm using loading spinner when ajax loading. But my problem is, when i'm using FixedColumns the loading spinner still showing on first column after ajax complete (first column is freezing). 
Here my code :

```
var table = $('#rep-real-import');
        var target = table.attr('data-table');
        var KPNo = $("#KPNo").val();
        var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
            if (processing) {
                $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
            } else{
                $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
            };
        }).DataTable({
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": 200,
            "paging": true,
            "fixedColumns":   {
                leftColumns: 1,
                rightColumns: 0
            },
            "ajax": {
                "url" : host+"datatables/"+target,
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "fnDrawCallback": function(oSetting) {
              $('.currency').formatCurrency({symbol: ''});
            }
        });
```

How i remove loading spinner on first column after ajax complete??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
var table = $('#rep-real-import');
    var target = table.attr('data-table');
    var KPNo = $("#KPNo").val();
    var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
        if (processing) {
            $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
        } else{
            $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
        };
    }).DataTable({
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": 200,
        "paging": true,
        "fixedColumns":   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            rightColumns: 0
        },
        "ajax": {
            "url" : host+"datatables/"+target,
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function(oSetting) {
          $('.currency').formatCurrency({symbol: ''});
        }
    });
```

Try this:

```
table = $('#rep-real-import');
    var target = table.attr('data-table');
    var KPNo = $("#KPNo").val();
    var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
        if (processing) {
            $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
        } else{
            $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
        };
    }).DataTable({
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": 200,
        "paging": true
        "ajax": {
            "url" : host+"datatables/"+target,
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function(oSetting) {
          $('.currency').formatCurrency({symbol: ''});
        }
    });
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table, {
            leftColumns: 1
        } );
```